# Azure App Gateway - Retain caller hostname in the user browser that calls App Gateway to prevent "possible CSRF detected - state parameter" error

Tags: spring-security, url-rewriting, csrf, azure-application-gateway

Requesting for some help here. Kind of stuck with a use case. We are trying to integrate OneLogin with our app via Spring security.

The entry point to our application is Azure App Gateway that routes the requests to load balancer further routing to the VMs where the service is deployed. Everything works fine if we DONOT override the hostname in Backend settings for any incoming request, leading to the App Gateway host only getting passed for every request. Here the App Gateway URL being set as the redirect URI in Spring security auth endpoint call.
[image: Backend settings in Azure App Gateway]

The problem appears when the Apigee is used as the entry point to our application. Apigee routes the request to App Gateway routing it further to load balancer and VMs. Here, we DO have to override the host as Apigee host name in order to authenticate the client to the OneLogin server. The Apigee endpoint is set as the redirect URI in the Spring security auth endpoint call. [image: Backend settings for overriding with Apigee URL]
However, the server responds back with "possible CSRF detected - state parameter was required but no state could be found" error. Tried different possible solutions from other SO links to resolve this error like providing a session cookie name, but did not help. Our OneLogin server and client application are also in different domains.

The only thing that works here is when we DONOT override the hostname in Azure App Gateway Backend settings and pass the App Gateway URL as the redirect URI in auth endpoint call. But the problem is it shows the App Gateway URL in the user browser, which we do not want because in an ideal scenario, the user should see only the Apigee host in the browser url and not the App Gateway host. So, is there any way to re-route/redirect/override the URL to Apigee URL in Azure App Gateway settings without the call being made to Apigee endpoint. Just the user sees the Apigee url in the browser, but internally all calls are made to App Gateway endpoint only.

Or the other solution could be to prevent the CSRF issue when Apigee hostname is used as the redirect URL in the auth endpoint instead of App Gateway host. But not sure how to resolve that.

Comment: I feel the other solution pointed above makes sense where we want to resolve the "Possible CSRF detected - state parameter was required but no state could be found" error. And while debugging this in my local, found out a new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext is getting used while the token endpoint call. This is caused I feel due to the usage of different jsessionId cookie in the token call than the one that was used earlier before the auth endpoint call. If the same jsessionId cookie is used in both the endpoint calls, probably this error will be resolved. Not sure how to pass the same jsessionId.

Comment: Able to find the root cause behind this issue. Posted the issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73923706/apigee-setting-cookie-in-the-redirect-request-header-of-apigee-that-was-set-ea , probably would be able to get some help there.

Answer (score 0):

•   In your scenario, **when you are not overriding the hostname in the Azure application gateway backend settings and pass the ‘Application Gateway’ URL as redirect URL in the ‘Authorization endpoint call’, the application gateway URL is shown in the user’s browser which is not desired since the Apigee host redirects the authentication requests to the ‘App gateway’ endpoint**.

Therefore, **without the call to be made to the ‘Apigee’ endpoint, you can surely redirect it to the Apigee redirect URL in the Azure application gateway settings by configuring the ‘Rewrite URI rules’ in the gateway. These rewrite rules will check for any presence of configured URLs or specific paths and will therefore, change the original URI path to the new path configured**. As a result, please follow the below given snapshots as steps for configuring the same as stated above: -

[image: Application gateway - 1]
[image: Application gateway - 2]
[image: Application gateway - 3]
[image: Application gateway - 4]

Thus, as shown above, you can **configure the ‘Rewrite rules’ in a ‘Standard V2’ SKU application gateway for redirecting response requests of ‘authorization endpoint call’ from application gateway URL to the Apigee endpoint hostname configured**. In this way, **when the application gateway URL is shown in the browser, it will be rewrited to the apigee endpoint hostname’s URL in the browser and accordingly the user at the receiving end will be able to see the Apigee endpoint hostname as a result fulfilling your requirement**.

For more details regarding the above, kindly refer the below link: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-url#modify-a-redirection-url***

Comment: Hi @Kartik thanks for your answer. Yes, we tried the exact same thing what you suggested. However the issue of CSRF detection remained. Have posted the solution to this problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/73986619/8642608 . Thanks for looking into this.