# Apigee - setting cookie in the redirect request header of Apigee that was set earlier by the application

Tags: cookies, spring-security, session-cookies, apigee, jsessionid

Scenario 1: `Working fine`
The application receives all the requests through Azure App Gateway. The application sets some value for the session cookie "JSESSIONID" in the response of first "/login" endpoint (set by Spring security). This same JSESSIONID cookie value is then used in the request header of "/login?code=<some_code>&state=<some_state>" api, which is the callback url from the Authorisation server. So, in this case, the auth server is able to identify the client based on same session cookie value. We can infer that Azure app Gateway sends the cookie forward. There is no specific settings done in App Gateway.

Scenario 2: `Issue`
Now the application receives the request through Azure App Gateway from Apigee. The callback url is also set to the apigee url. The application sets some value for the session cookie "JSESSIONID" in the response of first "/login" endpoint. But when the callback url "/login?code=<some_code>&state=<some_state>" is invoked after Auth server validation success, there is no "JSESSIONID" in the request header. So, possibly Apigee is stripping of this cookie.

The other cookies like "SameSite", "ADRUM_BTa" and "ADRUM_BT1" are passed in the request header of the callback url in both the scenarios.

Could someone please help here, if there is any settings change that needs to be done in Apigee so that it sends the cookie in the request header of callback url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by setting the session cookie path in the Application equal to the URI backend path of the Apigee configuration.

> server.servlet.session.cookie.path=/backend/path/configured/in/apigee/proxy

As the session cookies are always set based on path. By default, without the above code, the session cookie path was set to the server context path of the application.

Comment: Hi - I am facing similar challenge when redirecting form one URL to another in same domain in apigee, can you please suggest something? also where to set this path?

Comment: Hi @Rohit, need to understand the components that are involved in your flow. Like Apigee is calling which component and that in calls which component.
The above property can be set in the application's yaml file which will set the path for the cookie that will be generated by your application.

Comment: it was indeed an issue with the path, instead of setting a path from server I updated the proxy to match the path that was being returned. Doing this resolved the issue. Thank you for pointing this out, it really helped.